# Material-UI, create-react-library, testing-library/react, ThemeProvider and UT can not work

Tags: material-ui

Based on Material-UI, start from create-react-library, also finish many unit test cases along with testing-library/react, then comes problem

1. if want to pass unit test case, set @Material-UI as dependencies,
   then it causes "theme propagation issues", ThemeProvider not work as
   expected.
2. if set @Material-UI as peerDependencies, ThemeProvider works fine,
   but when run unit test case, it can't import component from
   @Material-UI.

anyone has some easy way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put `"@material-ui/*"` as peerDependencies.
2. Add a `config-overrides.js` in the root folder. for Jest setup
   `aliasMap`.

```js
const path = require('path');
const { aliasJest } = require('react-app-rewire-alias');

const aliasMap = {
  '@material-ui': path.join('./', 'example/node_modules/@material-ui')
};

module.exports = {
  jest: aliasJest(aliasMap)
};
```